# Grep and print back reference

Tags: bash, shell, grep, iptables

I have this iptable log:

```
Feb 25 10:32:48 XXX: [414645.555838] FW: DEN TCP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=XYZ SRC=1.1.1.1 DST=2.2.2.2 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80 DPT=51814 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

I want to grep 1.1.1.1 and 80 (SRC and SPT field). 
I do this:

```
grep -oP 'SRC=([^ ]+).+SPT=([0-9]+)' /var/log/iptables.log
```

But it returns:

```
SRC=1.1.1.1 DST=2.2.2.2 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=57 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=80
```

How do I get $1 and $2 only ( reference to the matched value)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `sed` approach:

```
sed -rn 's/.*SRC=([^ ]+).*SPT=([0-9]+).*/\1 \2/p' /var/log/iptables.log
```

You can pipe it to `while read src spt` in your script or something similar. Now this of course is not very efficient, because of three stars in the pattern, so if performance is an issue, you can consider using things like `cut` to extract certain fields:

```
cut -d' ' -f12,21 /var/log/iptables.log
```

Not sure if the log format is consistent enough for this to work.

Comment: thanks for the sed solution, that works. But I can't believe there's no such feature for grep..

Comment: To use sed in a grep-like fashion use: `sed -n 's/.../.../p' file` otherwise all lines will be printed.

Comment: @potong You're right, in this case I guess all lines match, but I'll edit anyway. Thanks

Comment: thats not with grep so -1 from me, sorry

Comment: Well.. you've `sed` it (*..joke.. said sed.. ohh.. nevermind..*) you can always pre-sed using grep, for example, limiting your finds to only first one using `... | grep --max-count=1 --only-matching --extended-regexp 'SRC=([^ ]+).+SPT=([0-9]+)' | sed ... `

Answer (score 11):

The main issue with your example is that you are trying to return groupings, this is not possible IIUC. One way around this is to use positive look-behind (see `man perlre`):

```
grep -oP '(?<=SRC=|SPT=)[^ ]*'
```

Output:

```
1.1.1.1
80
```

Here's a more portable alternative:

```
grep -o 'SRC=[^ ]*\|SPT=[^ ]*' | grep -o '[^=]*$'
```

If you want the output to be on one line, you should consider going one tool up, i.e. use *Lev's* answer. If you know that the output always comes in pairs, you could join the lines with `paste`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=SRC=|SPT=)[^ ]*' | paste - -
```

Or with `xargs`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=SRC=|SPT=)[^ ]*' | xargs -n2
```

Or `sed`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=SRC=|SPT=)[^ ]*' | sed 'N; s/\n/ /'
```