# GREP between 2 strings without PERL

Tags: regex, grep

I'd like to GREP something between 2 strings/chars without using `-P` ( PERL ) just with `-E` (`--extended-regexp`).

I know how to do it with awk, sed and grep -Po, that's not this question. I ask if this is possible to do it with `grep -E` only. Here is example between `(` and `)`:

Example:

```
echo "My IP=(192.168.0.1):205 bla bla" | grep -oE '\(\b.*\b\)'
```

This one works but i get result with `(` and `)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grep and print back reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067796/grep-and-print-back-reference)

Comment: I don't think just `grep -E` can get you that output.

Comment: Without lookahead/behinds it get's though to dump those `()`'s....

Comment: Why don't you want to use `grep -P` or `sed` or Awk or Perl, anyway?

Comment: It works with dual grep usage: echo "My IP=(192.168.0.1):205 bla bla" | grep -o '([^)]*' | grep -o '[^(].*'    but how about with just 1 grep execution?

Answer (score 0):

Given that in your sample text the text between the parans looks like an ip address, and that the rest of the text doesn't contain what looks like an ip address, you could simply omit the parans and look for IP addresses.

This expression will match strings which look like IP addresses, and limits octet to numeric values from 0 to 255.

`(1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.(1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.(1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.(1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])`

[image]

```
root@mysystem:~# echo "My IP=(192.168.0.1):205 bla bla" | grep -oE '(1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.(1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.(1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.(1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])'
192.168.0.1
root@mysystem:~#
```

Comment: Impressive :) but i think this is not what I asked for - match between string/character, not match IP adress. This is just example there could be anything inside.

Comment: Yeah the -oE options limit your use of look arounds, which then limits your options :(