# Find same rwx permissions between users-others using egrep

Tags: regex, permissions, grep, backreference

I have a list of seven files with different permissions

```
-rwxr-xrwx 1 user user 0 Jun  6 21:32  a1
--wx--x-wx 1 user user 0 Jun  6 21:32  a2
------x--- 1 user user 0 Jun  6 21:32  a3
-rw-r---w- 1 user user 0 Jun  6 21:32  a4
-r-xr-x--x 1 user user 0 Jun  6 21:32  a5
---x-wx-wx 1 user user 0 Jun  6 21:32  a6
---x--x--x 1 user user 0 Jun  6 21:32  a7
```

I need to find using egrep the files that the **user** has the **same permissions** with the **others**.
If `u=rw-` then `o=rw-`, if `u=r--` then `o=r--` etc. 
From these files only a1 and a2 have same user-others permissions.
I tried `ls -l | egrep '^..{2}.{2}.{2}'` but it doesn't work, probably because it checks if the preceding characters exist 2 times on the whole line.

Comment: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Don't you need to escape the curly brackets? Also, the use of back references might help, something like this: `ls | grep -e "^.\(.\{3\}\).\{3\}\1"`
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067796/grep-and-print-back-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a backreference:

```
ls -l | egrep '^.(...)...\1'
```

If you wanted just the filename you could then extract the 9th column:

```
ls -l | egrep '^.(...)...\1' | awk '{print $9}'
```

Comment: First line solved my problem. Seems that i had to use buffers. Thanks!